# Detox Error : No views in hierarchy found matching: (with tag value: is "email" and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE) in React Native

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, detox

I am doing a detox test for react-native android version 0.61.5. I am going to testing Login.js. I am able to go to the login screen but while testing elements in the login screen I am getting this error even though I mentioned testID. If clean the project no of times then it's working in android

> Error: androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with tag value: is "email" and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE)

```
 <TextInput
testID= 'email'
value={this.state.email}
placeholder="EMAIL"
```

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I am getting the same issue... it works for iOS

Comment: Close the node server and clean project or delete build folder and re-build then it's working